# How to make that formula work for a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I struggle to apply my formula for a range.

here what I have[image]

And here what I need
[image]

I success to reproduce the same schema with one row :
[image]

with this formula :
`={transpose(split(rept(A2&"|",9),"|")),transpose(split(rept(B2&"|",9),"|")),transpose({C1:K1}),transpose({C2:K2}),transpose(split(rept(U2&"|",9),"|")),transpose(split(rept(V2&"|",9),"|"))}`

but for the all range A2:V93
i try this but (and i have ommit the headers C1:K1 ) i have a error(**Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more columns** ) :
`=arrayformula({transpose(split(rept(A2:A93&"|",9),"|")),transpose(split(rept(B2:B93&"|",9),"|")),transpose({C2:K93}),transpose(split(rept(U2:U93&"|",9),"|")),transpose(split(rept(V2:93&"|",9),"|"))})`

and the last question how to do this.

[image]

I have try with this formula. but if i add transpose, it will transpose all cols to rows and its not why i want
`=arrayformula(split({{rept(A2:A93&"|",3)}},"|"))`

Thank you very much

EDIT : link => [sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1alhjC_wpWEToDG8PP6VurtaXo-RchPv8QZpGQUsZFcs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet, with sample data, to make it easier for others to help you on this.

Comment: thx for your resp, done, thx

Comment: if you make the link editable, it will make it easier for others to test and demonstrate solutions

Comment: oops here we go :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this "unpivoting" formula with Flatten should work for you.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(MK.Clean.Data!A2:A&"|"&MK.Clean.Data!B2:B&"#|"&TO_TEXT(MK.Clean.Data!U2:U)&"#|"&MK.Clean.Data!C1:T1&"|"&MK.Clean.Data!V2:V&"|"&MK.Clean.Data!C2:T),"|",0,0),"#",""),"where Col6<>'' order by Col1",0))
```

I should mention that FLATTEN() is an undocumented function that I only recently discovered.  I believe it is intended to remain "hidden" in the back end of the sheets programming, but if what I did is what you're after, there really isn't a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Neat! Here's a guide on how to use `FLATTEN()`: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/flatten-function-in-google-sheets/

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I know Prashanth.  He is pretty good in sheets had he's done a nice job on his site explaining how flatten works.   But i think it's important that people realize that the function is not here to stay.  I have spoken with Google Engineers about it recently and it could be taken out of sheets at any moment.